# Which SNES emulators can support >2 player (local) multiplayer?

Tags: emulation, snes

I am wondering which (if any) SNES emulators can support 3-4 player multiplayer locally on the same PC (with enough USB gamepads plugged in)? Many SNES games were excellent with 3/4 players (e.g. Mario Kart, Bomberman, Secret of Mana); however, it seems to be a bit unclear in the tech specs for many of the available emulators, to what extent they support 3-4 player local multiplayer.

I typically use bsnes, but I can't see any option in the settings to enable play with more than 2 controllers.

Answer (score 2):

I know [Bizhawk with the Snes 9x Core](https://tasvideos.org/Bizhawk) does as I just tried it out with NHL 98 for SNES. The only thing that is somewhat tricky is setting it up.

On the menu bar go `Snes -> Settings`

There go to to `Right Port -> Select Multitap`

[image: example multitap]

After that you can go to `Config -> Controllers` and you'll now see Player 1 through Player 5 tabs. Just configure the input with whatever USB devices you want to use.

[image: sample controllers]

Then launch the game:

[image]

Comment: This is a really helpful answer. I haven't tried this one before, but will check it out, thanks! I typically use bsnes, but couldn't see a similar setup option there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after seeing [Halfwarr's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/405642), I poked about a bit more in the settings for **bsnes**, and it seems it does also support 3+ player MP after all. In a similar way, in the input settings, you can set the right controller to 'multitap', then it allows you to set the control mappings for additional controllers.

I haven't tried it yet, but good to know!